# Equal to (=) operator in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2003 with VB.NET language. I wrote my query like

```
"UPDATE book SET status='confirm' WHERE idnum = '%" & daoi.Text & "%'"
```

but the data doensnt update. When I use this code

```
"UPDATE book SET status='confirm' WHERE idnum LIKE '%" & daoi.Text & "%'"
```

the data is updated.

Why I cannot use equal to in the statement?

Comment: The below link explains how the `LIKE` operator is used for searching for a specified pattern whereas `=` is used for exact comparisons in searches. http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 4):

The `%` character is a wildcard in SQL. You don't need it, when not using `LIKE`, but equals.

Your query should be `"UPDATE book SET status='confirm' WHERE idnum = '" & daoi.Text & "'"`

Plus: You should parameterize your query. [Always think of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 4):

In your equals statement you have the `%` sign. So it will only match any book ID's that have the `%` sign in the ID as well.

The `%` is a wildcard in the `LIKE` statement.

Answer (score 3):

`LIKE` and `=` are not the same and they are two different operators.

[`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) looks for partial matched strings - E.G.

```
'here is an example' LIKE '%exam%' -- TRUE
```

`=` looks for an exact match - E.G.

```
'here is an example' = '%exam%' -- FALSE
'exam' = 'exam' -- TRUE
```

Comment: mysterious downvotes for correct well-written answers...SO

Answer (score 2):

You can, assuming that `daoi.Text` contains the exact value that you are looking for:

```
"UPDATE book SET status='confirm' WHERE idnum = '" & daoi.Text & "'"
```

However please note that this kind of query building is **unsafe**: if the user (or perpetrator) types `5';DROP TABLE book;--` then a rather *different* query is executed compared to what you were expecting. This is known as SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

say if idnum column contains a value 'A0001',
When you execute your first query '`WHERE idnum = '%" & daoi.Text & "%'"`',this will try to match with equality operation ie `'A0001'='%A0001%'` which is not correct.

When you apply your second query '`WHERE idnum LIKE '%" & daoi.Text & "%'"`', this will try to match the column value with the input data using partial matches.ie.`'A0001'LIKE '%A0001%'` So this will work.

if you wanted to learn more about like operator ,see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)